# How to costumize bar chart in ggplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, bar-chart, visualization

I have a mirrored bar-chart, and I want avoid mirror bars and have the same graphs but 2 columns for each category:

1. Negative and positive (firstly positive values on right side and below negative values on left side)
2. Colours must be determined by 'Model' categorical variable and pos & neg values need to be different, like fully coloured bars = positive, bounded (with the same colour) but not filled bars = negative.
3. Also, USA based values must be on the top and Canada based values below

```
df <- data.frame (Origin = c("Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA"),
                  Model = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                  poschange = c(60, 45,34,56, 65, 44,40, 55, 35, 24,34,12),
                  negchange = c(-5,-2,-0.5,-2,-1,-0.05,-1,-3,-0.1,-3,-1.5,-0.9))

require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(tidyr)


df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(., cols=c('poschange','negchange'),
                           names_to = 'value_category')
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(Groups = paste(Origin, Model))
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(label_position=ifelse(value>0, value-5,value-8)) # adjusting label position
df2 %>% arrange(value) %>% ggplot(aes(x=value, y=reorder(Groups,value), 
                                      fill=value_category, 
                                      group=value_category))+
  geom_col(width=0.75)
coord_flip()
```

Output:
[image]

Desired output (something like this but colours must be corresponding to Model cat. variable):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

1. Use an `ifelse` statement to label the negative values as "white"
2. To have a `fill` of white, use `scale_fill_manual` with a `my_color` palette
3. To avoid "mirrored" bars, use `position = "dodge"`
4. To have negative and positive values side-by-side, you need to swap your `x` and `y` argument in `ggplot`
5. To avoid overlapping text on the x-axis, use `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))`
6. Use the `breaks` argument in both `scale_xxx_manual` function to remove the "white" label in the legend

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame (Origin = c("Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA"),
                  Model = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                  poschange = c(60, 45,34,56, 65, 44,40, 55, 35, 24,34,12),
                  negchange = c(-5,-2,-0.5,-2,-1,-0.05,-1,-3,-0.1,-3,-1.5,-0.9))

df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(., cols=c('poschange','negchange'),
                           names_to = 'value_category') %>% 
  mutate(Groups = paste(Origin, Model),
         value_category = factor(value_category, levels = c("negchange", "poschange")))

my_color = c("A" = '#7fc97f', "B" = '#beaed4', "C" = '#fdc086', 
             "D" = '#ffff99', "E" = '#386cb0', "F" = '#f0027f', "white" = "white")

ggplot(df2, aes(value, Model, 
                fill = ifelse(value_category == "negchange", "white", Model), 
                color = Model)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_color, breaks = df2$Model) +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_color, breaks = df2$Model) +
  labs(fill = "Model") +
  facet_grid(Origin ~ ., switch = "y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Almost. but instead of blue bars, they need to be the same colours as are bounds. For instance in case of Canada A, top bard needs to be in pink, and below as it is

Comment: @user4567794374545 See my update :)

Comment: perfect! but is it possible to remove multiple Canada and USA texts and leave only one as indicated on my desired output?

Comment: @user4567794374545 See my update again :)

Comment: one more question, can I order bars in Canada and in USA descending by positive values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72977155/how-to-do-conditional-grouping-of-data-in-r/72978298#72978298